# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol threadIdx

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2019

I'm moving into C++/Cuda and ran into a compile error 'unresolved external symbol threadIdx' in 'MortalityTable.obj'.

I created a new C++ Cuda Runtime project, than compiles and runs fine. 
Then added a class `MortalityTable.cu` and `.h`, without any Cuda code, just regular C++. That compiles and runs fine.

The error starts when I try to add the Cuda kernel (If I comment it out all is well). I have these headers in MortalityTable.cu:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

And this is my kernel in that same file

```
__global__
void DevPLE(double* devple, double* devQxt, int maxAge, int years) {
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    double surv = 0, ple = 0;
    for (int age = 0; age < maxAge; age++) {
        surv = surv * (1.0f - devQxt[age * years + i]);
        ple += surv;
    }
    devple[i] = ple + 0.5;
}
```

Any ideas how I can get this to compile and run?
I still have the example code in `kernel.cu` when you create a new Cuda Runtime Project, it has the same headers and does work. So it seems the project setup is ok, but for some reason does not work for MortalityTable.cu...

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just an Intellisense error? As you can see [here](https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/bjL887) there is nothing wrong with the code

Comment: Yeah it's 'build failed' with LNK2001.. Adn indeed I wouldn;t know what's wrong with it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.cu file are compiled with nvcc, .c .cpp are compiled with cl.

When in a cuda project, you add a c++ file (cpp), but then you rename it with the .cu extension, VS won't also change the compiler.

If you edit you project file project.vcxproj you might want to check that your .cu file is included in a CudaCompile markup:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <CudaCompile Include="cudacode.cu" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="code.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You can more easily change this by right clicking on the `.cu` file, select properties and change the `item type` to `CUDA C/C++` for `.cu` files and `C/C++ header` in case of `.h*` files.